# iOS Swift App with Firebase crashes with 'Index out of range' if user taps on cell before page has finished loading

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On VC # 1 I have a tableview that is populated by Firebase. If you tap on a cell you go to VC # 2 which has that cell's details which you can edit.

If you use the app slowly everything and tap on a cell, edit, and then save and return to VC 1 the app runs fine.

However, if you are quick.. even just slightly and tap on a cell while it is reloading everything it will crash

It says **Index Out Of Range**

And I this pops up

What is the best way to prevent this?

I can post my code if you need me to. Just let me know if you want the func that pulls the data..the did select...the cell for row etc and I will edit my post.

Thank you.

[image: error screen]

**My Code**

```
    func pullCardData() {
    serviceArray.removeAll()
    let cardRef = ref.child("cards")
    cardRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
      for cards in snapshot.children {
        let allCardIDs = (cards as AnyObject).key as String
        if allCardIDs == self.cardID {
          let thisCardLocation = cardRef.child(self.cardID)
          thisCardLocation.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let thisCardDetails = snapshot as FIRDataSnapshot
            let cardDict = thisCardDetails.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.selectedCard.cardID = thisCardDetails.key
            self.selectedCard.nickname = cardDict["nickname"] as! String
            self.selectedCard.type = cardDict["type"] as! String
            self.pullServicesForCard()
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }


  func pullServicesForCard() {
    let thisCardServices = self.ref.child("cards").child(self.cardID).child("services")
    let serviceRefLoc = self.ref.child("services")
    thisCardServices.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {serviceSnap in
      if serviceSnap.hasChildren() {
        for serviceChild in serviceSnap.children {
          let serviceID = (serviceChild as AnyObject).key as String
          serviceRefLoc.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {allServiceSnap in
            if allServiceSnap.hasChildren() {
              for all in allServiceSnap.children {
                let allServs = (all as AnyObject).key as String
                let thisServiceLocationInServiceNode = self.ref.child("services").child(serviceID)
                if serviceID == allServs {
                  thisServiceLocationInServiceNode.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {thisSnap in
                    let serv = thisSnap as FIRDataSnapshot
                    let serviceDict = serv.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    let aService = ServiceClass()
                    self.serviceCurrent = serviceDict["serviceStatus"] as? Bool
                    self.serviceName = serviceDict["serviceName"] as? String
                    self.serviceURL = serviceDict["serviceURL"] as? String
                    self.serviceFixedBool = serviceDict["serviceFixed"] as? Bool
                    self.serviceFixedAmount = serviceDict["serviceAmount"] as? String
                    self.attentionInt = serviceDict["attentionInt"] as? Int

                    aService.serviceUrl = serviceDict["serviceURL"] as! String
                    aService.serviceName = serviceDict["serviceName"] as! String
                    aService.serviceStatus = serviceDict["serviceStatus"] as? Bool
                    aService.serviceAttention = serviceDict["attentionInt"] as! Int


                    self.totalArr.append((serviceDict["serviceAmount"] as? String)!)

                    self.doubleArray = self.totalArr.flatMap{ Double($0) }
                    let arraySum = self.doubleArray.reduce(0, +)
                    self.cardNickNameLabel.text = "\(self.selectedCard.nickname) Fixed Expense is \(arraySum)"

                    aService.serviceID = serviceID
                    if serviceDict["serviceStatus"] as? Bool == true {
                      self.selectedCard.cStatus = true
                    } else {
                      self.selectedCard.cStatus = false
                    }
                    self.serviceArray.append(aService)

                    self.serviceArray.sort {
                      if $0.serviceAttention == $1.serviceAttention { return $0.serviceName < $1.serviceName }
                      return $0.serviceAttention > $1.serviceAttention
                    }

                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                  })
                }
              }
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }


...

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let row = indexPath.row

selectedService = serviceArray[row].serviceID as String
if selectedService != "" {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromCardDetailsToEditService", sender: self)
}
}



  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serviceCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ServiceTableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.serviceStatusView.createRoundView()
    if serviceArray[row].serviceStatus == true {
      cell.serviceStatusView.backgroundColor = .green
    } else {
      cell.serviceStatusView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    cell.serviceNameLabel.text = serviceArray[row].serviceName


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      let myURLString: String = "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=\(self.serviceArray[row].serviceUrl)"
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let myURL = URL(string: myURLString), let myData = try? Data(contentsOf: myURL), let image = UIImage(data: myData) {
          cell.serviceLogoImage.image = image
        } else {
          cell.serviceLogoImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "\(self.getLetterOrNumberAndChooseImage(text: self.serviceArray[row].serviceName))")
        }

      }
    }
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your code that you are currently using.

Comment: @NiravD I posted my code, its a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem in the past and solved it with reloading the tableview asynchronously (In Swift 3 and later):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
```